# How to turn off autoselect in date type input (react-date-picker)

Tags: css, reactjs, input, react-datepicker

Is there any way to turn off autoselecting date input value on first click in react-date-picker?

Thats what I have

[image: Thats what I have]

And thats what I want

[image: And thats what I want]

Im fighting with css, webkit, :active etc. and I can't get what I am expecting for

Comment: show your code!!

Comment: Sorry, but it's nothing special, just imported DatePicker from 'react-date-picker' and slightly pimped via styled-components. 
https://i.imgur.com/VgUy9nP.png

Answer (score 0):

I have found way to achieve what I want. Clear React-date-picker looks like on image below
[image: react-date-picker]

I wanted to have just date like on screen in my question but without selecting value on click. To do this I deleted 'x' icon (display none) and set calendar icon opacity to 0 and stretched this icon for the whole input. Not very sophisticated, but it works.